# combine two built in pine script indicators facing scaling problem

Tags: pine-script

i'm working on a script to combine two built in indicators in one script (RSI & technical rating)
but i'm facing scaling problem I've tried and reached at this result [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zoB7.jpg) as you can see in this picture i've successfully placed y location of labels inside RSI but the histogram of other indicator is down below marked in red circle which looks like [this(picture 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPXcV.jpg) after lot of zooming in.

so i want the both the indicators to overlayed on each other like in this image [picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcjT9.jpg)  this is done with moving two indicators in one pane , but i want this same result with only using one pine script
can anyone help me

thank you

here's my combined code

```
//@version=4
study(title="Technical Ratings", shorttitle="Technicals", precision=2)
res = input("", title="Indicator Timeframe", type=input.resolution)
ratingSignal = input(defval = "All", title = "Rating is based on", options = ["MAs", "Oscillators", "All"])
// Awesome Oscillator
AO() => 
    sma(hl2, 5) - sma(hl2, 34)
// Stochastic RSI
StochRSI() =>
    rsi1 = rsi(close, 14)
    K = sma(stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, 14), 3)
    D = sma(K, 3)
    [K, D]
// Ultimate Oscillator
tl() => close[1] < low ? close[1]: low
uo(ShortLen, MiddlLen, LongLen) =>
    Value1 = sum(tr, ShortLen)
    Value2 = sum(tr, MiddlLen)
    Value3 = sum(tr, LongLen)
    Value4 = sum(close - tl(), ShortLen)
    Value5 = sum(close - tl(), MiddlLen)
    Value6 = sum(close - tl(), LongLen)
    float UO = na
    if Value1 != 0 and Value2 != 0 and Value3 != 0
        var0 = LongLen / ShortLen
        var1 = LongLen / MiddlLen
        Value7 = (Value4 / Value1) * (var0)
        Value8 = (Value5 / Value2) * (var1)
        Value9 = (Value6 / Value3)
        UO := (Value7 + Value8 + Value9) / (var0 + var1 + 1)
    UO
// Ichimoku Cloud
donchian(len) => avg(lowest(len), highest(len))
ichimoku_cloud() =>
    conversionLine = donchian(9)
    baseLine = donchian(26)
    leadLine1 = avg(conversionLine, baseLine)
    leadLine2 = donchian(52)
    [conversionLine, baseLine, leadLine1, leadLine2]
    
calcRatingMA(ma, src) => na(ma) or na(src) ? na : (ma == src ? 0 : ( ma < src ? 1 : -1 ))
calcRating(buy, sell) => buy ? 1 : ( sell ? -1 : 0 )
calcRatingAll() =>
    //============== MA =================
    SMA10 = sma(close, 10)
    SMA20 = sma(close, 20)
    SMA30 = sma(close, 30)
    SMA50 = sma(close, 50)
    SMA100 = sma(close, 100)
    SMA200 = sma(close, 200)
    
    EMA10 = ema(close, 10)
    EMA20 = ema(close, 20)
    EMA30 = ema(close, 30)
    EMA50 = ema(close, 50)
    EMA100 = ema(close, 100)
    EMA200 = ema(close, 200)
    
    HullMA9 = hma(close, 9)
    
    // Volume Weighted Moving Average (VWMA)
    VWMA = vwma(close, 20)
    
    [IC_CLine, IC_BLine, IC_Lead1, IC_Lead2] = ichimoku_cloud()
    
    // ======= Other =============
    // Relative Strength Index, RSI
    RSI = rsi(close,14)
    
    // Stochastic
    lengthStoch = 14
    smoothKStoch = 3
    smoothDStoch = 3
    kStoch = sma(stoch(close, high, low, lengthStoch), smoothKStoch)
    dStoch = sma(kStoch, smoothDStoch)
    
    // Commodity Channel Index, CCI
    CCI = cci(close, 20)
    
    // Average Directional Index
    float adxValue = na, float adxPlus = na, float adxMinus = na
    [P, M, V] = dmi(14, 14)
    adxValue := V
    adxPlus := P
    adxMinus := M
    // Awesome Oscillator
    ao = AO()
    
    // Momentum
    Mom = mom(close, 10)
    // Moving Average Convergence/Divergence, MACD
    [macdMACD, signalMACD, _] = macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
    // Stochastic RSI
    [Stoch_RSI_K, Stoch_RSI_D] = StochRSI()
    // Williams Percent Range
    WR = wpr(14)
    
    // Bull / Bear Power
    BullPower = high - ema(close, 13)
    BearPower = low - ema(close, 13)
    // Ultimate Oscillator
    UO = uo(7,14,28)
    if not na(UO)
        UO := UO * 100
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    PriceAvg = ema(close, 50)
    DownTrend = close < PriceAvg
    UpTrend = close > PriceAvg
    // calculate trading recommendation based on SMA/EMA
    float ratingMA = 0
    float ratingMAC = 0
    
    if not na(SMA10)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(SMA10, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(SMA20)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(SMA20, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(SMA30)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(SMA30, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(SMA50)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(SMA50, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(SMA100)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(SMA100, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(SMA200)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(SMA200, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(EMA10)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(EMA10, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(EMA20)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(EMA20, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(EMA30)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(EMA30, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(EMA50)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(EMA50, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(EMA100)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(EMA100, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(EMA200)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(EMA200, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    
    if not na(HullMA9)
        ratingHullMA9 = calcRatingMA(HullMA9, close)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingHullMA9
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    
    if not na(VWMA)
        ratingVWMA = calcRatingMA(VWMA, close)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingVWMA
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    
    float ratingIC = na
    if not (na(IC_Lead1) or na(IC_Lead2) or na(close) or na(close[1]) or na(IC_BLine) or na(IC_CLine))
        ratingIC := calcRating(
         IC_Lead1 > IC_Lead2 and close > IC_Lead1 and close < IC_BLine and close[1] < IC_CLine and close > IC_CLine,
         IC_Lead2 > IC_Lead1 and close < IC_Lead2 and close > IC_BLine and close[1] > IC_CLine and close < IC_CLine)
    if not na(ratingIC)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingIC
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    
    ratingMA := ratingMAC > 0 ? ratingMA / ratingMAC : na
    
    float ratingOther = 0
    float ratingOtherC = 0
    
    ratingRSI = RSI
    if not(na(ratingRSI) or na(ratingRSI[1]))
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + calcRating(ratingRSI < 30 and ratingRSI[1] < ratingRSI, ratingRSI > 70 and ratingRSI[1] > ratingRSI)
    
    if not(na(kStoch) or na(dStoch) or na(kStoch[1]) or na(dStoch[1]))
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + calcRating(kStoch < 20 and dStoch < 20 and kStoch > dStoch and kStoch[1] < dStoch[1], kStoch > 80 and dStoch > 80 and kStoch < dStoch and kStoch[1] > dStoch[1])
    
    ratingCCI = CCI
    if not(na(ratingCCI) or na(ratingCCI[1]))
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + calcRating(ratingCCI < -100 and ratingCCI > ratingCCI[1], ratingCCI > 100 and ratingCCI < ratingCCI[1])
    
    if not(na(adxValue) or na(adxPlus[1]) or na(adxMinus[1]) or na(adxPlus) or na(adxMinus))
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + calcRating(adxValue > 20 and adxPlus[1] < adxMinus[1] and adxPlus > adxMinus, adxValue > 20 and adxPlus[1] > adxMinus[1] and adxPlus < adxMinus)
    
    if not(na(ao) or na(ao[1]))
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + calcRating(crossover(ao,0) or (ao > 0 and ao[1] > 0 and ao > ao[1] and ao[2] > ao[1]), crossunder(ao,0) or (ao < 0 and ao[1] < 0 and ao < ao[1] and ao[2] < ao[1]))
    
    if not(na(Mom) or na(Mom[1]))
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + calcRating(Mom > Mom[1], Mom < Mom[1])
    
    if not(na(macdMACD) or na(signalMACD))
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + calcRating(macdMACD > signalMACD, macdMACD < signalMACD)
    
    float ratingStoch_RSI = na
    if not(na(DownTrend) or na(UpTrend) or na(Stoch_RSI_K) or na(Stoch_RSI_D) or na(Stoch_RSI_K[1]) or na(Stoch_RSI_D[1]))
        ratingStoch_RSI := calcRating(
         DownTrend and Stoch_RSI_K < 20 and Stoch_RSI_D < 20 and Stoch_RSI_K > Stoch_RSI_D and Stoch_RSI_K[1] < Stoch_RSI_D[1],
         UpTrend and Stoch_RSI_K > 80 and Stoch_RSI_D > 80 and Stoch_RSI_K < Stoch_RSI_D and Stoch_RSI_K[1] > Stoch_RSI_D[1])
    if not na(ratingStoch_RSI)
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingStoch_RSI
    
    float ratingWR = na
    if not(na(WR) or na(WR[1]))
        ratingWR := calcRating(WR < -80 and WR > WR[1], WR > -20 and WR < WR[1])
    if not na(ratingWR)
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingWR
    
    float ratingBBPower = na
    if not(na(UpTrend) or na(DownTrend) or na(BearPower) or na(BearPower[1]) or na(BullPower) or na(BullPower[1]))
        ratingBBPower := calcRating(
         UpTrend and BearPower < 0 and BearPower > BearPower[1],
         DownTrend and BullPower > 0 and BullPower < BullPower[1])
    if not na(ratingBBPower)
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingBBPower
    
    float ratingUO = na
    if not(na(UO))
        ratingUO := calcRating(UO > 70, UO < 30)
    if not na(ratingUO)
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingUO
    
    ratingOther := ratingOtherC > 0 ? ratingOther / ratingOtherC : na
    
    float ratingTotal = 0
    float ratingTotalC = 0
    if not na(ratingMA)
        ratingTotal := ratingTotal + ratingMA
        ratingTotalC := ratingTotalC + 1
    if not na(ratingOther)
        ratingTotal := ratingTotal + ratingOther
        ratingTotalC := ratingTotalC + 1
    ratingTotal := ratingTotalC > 0 ? ratingTotal / ratingTotalC : na
    
    [ratingTotal, ratingOther, ratingMA, ratingOtherC, ratingMAC]
[ratingTotal, ratingOther, ratingMA, ratingOtherC, ratingMAC]  = security(syminfo.tickerid, res, calcRatingAll())
StrongBound = 0.5
WeakBound = 0.1
getSignal(ratingTotal, ratingOther, ratingMA) =>
    float _res = ratingTotal
    if ratingSignal == "MAs"
        _res := ratingMA
    if ratingSignal == "Oscillators"
        _res := ratingOther
    _res
tradeSignal = getSignal(ratingTotal, ratingOther, ratingMA)


poscol = input(color.blue, "Buy Color")
neutralcolor = input(color.gray, "Neutral Color")
negcol = input(color.red, "Sell Color")
poscond = tradeSignal > WeakBound
negcond = tradeSignal < -WeakBound
posseries = poscond ? tradeSignal : 0
negseries = negcond ? tradeSignal : 0
count_rising(plot) =>
    v_plot = plot > 0 ? plot : -plot
    var count = 0
    if v_plot == 0
        count := 0
    else if v_plot >= v_plot[1]
        count := min(5, count + 1)
    else if v_plot < v_plot[1]
        count := max(1, count - 1)
    count
poscount = count_rising(posseries)
negcount = count_rising(negseries)
_pc = poscond ? poscount : negcond ? negcount : 0
colorTransp(col, transp) =>
    red = color.r(col)
    green = color.g(col)
    blue = color.b(col)
    color.rgb(red, green, blue, transp)
hline(70, color=colorTransp(poscol, 50), linestyle=hline.style_solid)
hline(0.5, color=colorTransp(poscol, 50), linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
hline(-1, color=colorTransp(negcol, 50), linestyle=hline.style_solid)
hline(-0.5, color=colorTransp(negcol, 50), linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
getTimeOfNextBar() =>
    currentTime = time(timeframe.period)
    changeTime = change(currentTime)
    minChange = if (not na(changeTime))
        var float minChange = changeTime
        minChange := min(minChange, changeTime)
    int(currentTime + minChange)
drawInfo(txt, value) =>
    var info = label.new(50, 50, "", yloc = yloc.price, xloc = xloc.bar_time, textalign = text.align_left, textcolor = color.white)
    label.set_x(info, getTimeOfNextBar())
    label.set_text(info, txt)
    label.set_color(info, poscond ? poscol : negcond ? negcol : color.gray)
    label.set_style(info, label.style_label_left)
calcRatingStatus(value) =>
    if -StrongBound > value
        "Strong Sell"
    else if value < -WeakBound
        "Sell"
    else if value > StrongBound
        "Strong Buy"
    else if value > WeakBound
        "Buy"
    else
        "Neutral"
MAText = ratingMAC == 0 ? "" : "MAs:     " + calcRatingStatus(ratingMA) + "\n"
OtherText = ratingOtherC == 0 ? "" : "Oscillators: " + calcRatingStatus(ratingOther) + "\n"
TotaText = "All:  " + calcRatingStatus(ratingTotal)
drawInfo(MAText + OtherText + TotaText, tradeSignal)
col_buy = color.from_gradient(tradeSignal, 0.0, 0.2, neutralcolor, poscol)
col_sell = color.from_gradient(tradeSignal, -0.2, 0.0, negcol, neutralcolor)
col_gradient = color.from_gradient(tradeSignal, -0.2, 0.2, col_sell, col_buy)
plot(tradeSignal, title="Rating", linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_columns, color = colorTransp(col_gradient, 50 - _pc * 10))
_cond1 = crossunder(tradeSignal, -WeakBound)
alertcondition(_cond1, "Sell", "Ratings changed to Sell")
_cond2 = crossover(tradeSignal, WeakBound)
alertcondition(_cond2, "Buy", "Ratings changed to Buy")
_cond3 = crossunder(tradeSignal, -StrongBound)
alertcondition(_cond3, "Strong Sell", "Ratings changed to Strong Sell")
_cond4 = crossover(tradeSignal, StrongBound)
alertcondition(_cond4, "Strong Buy", "Ratings changed to Strong Buy")


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////      RSI      ///////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


len = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source", type = input.source)
up = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#8E1599)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#C0C0C0)
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#C0C0C0)
fill(band1, band0, color=#9915FF, transp=90, title="Background")
```

built in code of RSI

```
//@version=4
study(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")
len = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source", type = input.source)
up = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#8E1599)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#C0C0C0)
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#C0C0C0)
fill(band1, band0, color=#9915FF, transp=90, title="Background")
```

built in code of technical ratings

```
//@version=4
study(title="Technical Ratings", shorttitle="Technicals", precision=2)
res = input("", title="Indicator Timeframe", type=input.resolution)
ratingSignal = input(defval = "All", title = "Rating is based on", options = ["MAs", "Oscillators", "All"])
// Awesome Oscillator
AO() => 
    sma(hl2, 5) - sma(hl2, 34)
// Stochastic RSI
StochRSI() =>
    rsi1 = rsi(close, 14)
    K = sma(stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, 14), 3)
    D = sma(K, 3)
    [K, D]
// Ultimate Oscillator
tl() => close[1] < low ? close[1]: low
uo(ShortLen, MiddlLen, LongLen) =>
    Value1 = sum(tr, ShortLen)
    Value2 = sum(tr, MiddlLen)
    Value3 = sum(tr, LongLen)
    Value4 = sum(close - tl(), ShortLen)
    Value5 = sum(close - tl(), MiddlLen)
    Value6 = sum(close - tl(), LongLen)
    float UO = na
    if Value1 != 0 and Value2 != 0 and Value3 != 0
        var0 = LongLen / ShortLen
        var1 = LongLen / MiddlLen
        Value7 = (Value4 / Value1) * (var0)
        Value8 = (Value5 / Value2) * (var1)
        Value9 = (Value6 / Value3)
        UO := (Value7 + Value8 + Value9) / (var0 + var1 + 1)
    UO
// Ichimoku Cloud
donchian(len) => avg(lowest(len), highest(len))
ichimoku_cloud() =>
    conversionLine = donchian(9)
    baseLine = donchian(26)
    leadLine1 = avg(conversionLine, baseLine)
    leadLine2 = donchian(52)
    [conversionLine, baseLine, leadLine1, leadLine2]
    
calcRatingMA(ma, src) => na(ma) or na(src) ? na : (ma == src ? 0 : ( ma < src ? 1 : -1 ))
calcRating(buy, sell) => buy ? 1 : ( sell ? -1 : 0 )
calcRatingAll() =>
    //============== MA =================
    SMA10 = sma(close, 10)
    SMA20 = sma(close, 20)
    SMA30 = sma(close, 30)
    SMA50 = sma(close, 50)
    SMA100 = sma(close, 100)
    SMA200 = sma(close, 200)
    
    EMA10 = ema(close, 10)
    EMA20 = ema(close, 20)
    EMA30 = ema(close, 30)
    EMA50 = ema(close, 50)
    EMA100 = ema(close, 100)
    EMA200 = ema(close, 200)
    
    HullMA9 = hma(close, 9)
    
    // Volume Weighted Moving Average (VWMA)
    VWMA = vwma(close, 20)
    
    [IC_CLine, IC_BLine, IC_Lead1, IC_Lead2] = ichimoku_cloud()
    
    // ======= Other =============
    // Relative Strength Index, RSI
    RSI = rsi(close,14)
    
    // Stochastic
    lengthStoch = 14
    smoothKStoch = 3
    smoothDStoch = 3
    kStoch = sma(stoch(close, high, low, lengthStoch), smoothKStoch)
    dStoch = sma(kStoch, smoothDStoch)
    
    // Commodity Channel Index, CCI
    CCI = cci(close, 20)
    
    // Average Directional Index
    float adxValue = na, float adxPlus = na, float adxMinus = na
    [P, M, V] = dmi(14, 14)
    adxValue := V
    adxPlus := P
    adxMinus := M
    // Awesome Oscillator
    ao = AO()
    
    // Momentum
    Mom = mom(close, 10)
    // Moving Average Convergence/Divergence, MACD
    [macdMACD, signalMACD, _] = macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
    // Stochastic RSI
    [Stoch_RSI_K, Stoch_RSI_D] = StochRSI()
    // Williams Percent Range
    WR = wpr(14)
    
    // Bull / Bear Power
    BullPower = high - ema(close, 13)
    BearPower = low - ema(close, 13)
    // Ultimate Oscillator
    UO = uo(7,14,28)
    if not na(UO)
        UO := UO * 100
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    PriceAvg = ema(close, 50)
    DownTrend = close < PriceAvg
    UpTrend = close > PriceAvg
    // calculate trading recommendation based on SMA/EMA
    float ratingMA = 0
    float ratingMAC = 0
    
    if not na(SMA10)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(SMA10, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(SMA20)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(SMA20, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(SMA30)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(SMA30, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(SMA50)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(SMA50, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(SMA100)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(SMA100, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(SMA200)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(SMA200, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(EMA10)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(EMA10, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(EMA20)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(EMA20, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(EMA30)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(EMA30, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(EMA50)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(EMA50, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(EMA100)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(EMA100, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    if not na(EMA200)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + calcRatingMA(EMA200, close)
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    
    if not na(HullMA9)
        ratingHullMA9 = calcRatingMA(HullMA9, close)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingHullMA9
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    
    if not na(VWMA)
        ratingVWMA = calcRatingMA(VWMA, close)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingVWMA
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    
    float ratingIC = na
    if not (na(IC_Lead1) or na(IC_Lead2) or na(close) or na(close[1]) or na(IC_BLine) or na(IC_CLine))
        ratingIC := calcRating(
         IC_Lead1 > IC_Lead2 and close > IC_Lead1 and close < IC_BLine and close[1] < IC_CLine and close > IC_CLine,
         IC_Lead2 > IC_Lead1 and close < IC_Lead2 and close > IC_BLine and close[1] > IC_CLine and close < IC_CLine)
    if not na(ratingIC)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingIC
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    
    ratingMA := ratingMAC > 0 ? ratingMA / ratingMAC : na
    
    float ratingOther = 0
    float ratingOtherC = 0
    
    ratingRSI = RSI
    if not(na(ratingRSI) or na(ratingRSI[1]))
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + calcRating(ratingRSI < 30 and ratingRSI[1] < ratingRSI, ratingRSI > 70 and ratingRSI[1] > ratingRSI)
    
    if not(na(kStoch) or na(dStoch) or na(kStoch[1]) or na(dStoch[1]))
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + calcRating(kStoch < 20 and dStoch < 20 and kStoch > dStoch and kStoch[1] < dStoch[1], kStoch > 80 and dStoch > 80 and kStoch < dStoch and kStoch[1] > dStoch[1])
    
    ratingCCI = CCI
    if not(na(ratingCCI) or na(ratingCCI[1]))
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + calcRating(ratingCCI < -100 and ratingCCI > ratingCCI[1], ratingCCI > 100 and ratingCCI < ratingCCI[1])
    
    if not(na(adxValue) or na(adxPlus[1]) or na(adxMinus[1]) or na(adxPlus) or na(adxMinus))
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + calcRating(adxValue > 20 and adxPlus[1] < adxMinus[1] and adxPlus > adxMinus, adxValue > 20 and adxPlus[1] > adxMinus[1] and adxPlus < adxMinus)
    
    if not(na(ao) or na(ao[1]))
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + calcRating(crossover(ao,0) or (ao > 0 and ao[1] > 0 and ao > ao[1] and ao[2] > ao[1]), crossunder(ao,0) or (ao < 0 and ao[1] < 0 and ao < ao[1] and ao[2] < ao[1]))
    
    if not(na(Mom) or na(Mom[1]))
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + calcRating(Mom > Mom[1], Mom < Mom[1])
    
    if not(na(macdMACD) or na(signalMACD))
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + calcRating(macdMACD > signalMACD, macdMACD < signalMACD)
    
    float ratingStoch_RSI = na
    if not(na(DownTrend) or na(UpTrend) or na(Stoch_RSI_K) or na(Stoch_RSI_D) or na(Stoch_RSI_K[1]) or na(Stoch_RSI_D[1]))
        ratingStoch_RSI := calcRating(
         DownTrend and Stoch_RSI_K < 20 and Stoch_RSI_D < 20 and Stoch_RSI_K > Stoch_RSI_D and Stoch_RSI_K[1] < Stoch_RSI_D[1],
         UpTrend and Stoch_RSI_K > 80 and Stoch_RSI_D > 80 and Stoch_RSI_K < Stoch_RSI_D and Stoch_RSI_K[1] > Stoch_RSI_D[1])
    if not na(ratingStoch_RSI)
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingStoch_RSI
    
    float ratingWR = na
    if not(na(WR) or na(WR[1]))
        ratingWR := calcRating(WR < -80 and WR > WR[1], WR > -20 and WR < WR[1])
    if not na(ratingWR)
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingWR
    
    float ratingBBPower = na
    if not(na(UpTrend) or na(DownTrend) or na(BearPower) or na(BearPower[1]) or na(BullPower) or na(BullPower[1]))
        ratingBBPower := calcRating(
         UpTrend and BearPower < 0 and BearPower > BearPower[1],
         DownTrend and BullPower > 0 and BullPower < BullPower[1])
    if not na(ratingBBPower)
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingBBPower
    
    float ratingUO = na
    if not(na(UO))
        ratingUO := calcRating(UO > 70, UO < 30)
    if not na(ratingUO)
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingUO
    
    ratingOther := ratingOtherC > 0 ? ratingOther / ratingOtherC : na
    
    float ratingTotal = 0
    float ratingTotalC = 0
    if not na(ratingMA)
        ratingTotal := ratingTotal + ratingMA
        ratingTotalC := ratingTotalC + 1
    if not na(ratingOther)
        ratingTotal := ratingTotal + ratingOther
        ratingTotalC := ratingTotalC + 1
    ratingTotal := ratingTotalC > 0 ? ratingTotal / ratingTotalC : na
    
    [ratingTotal, ratingOther, ratingMA, ratingOtherC, ratingMAC]
[ratingTotal, ratingOther, ratingMA, ratingOtherC, ratingMAC]  = security(syminfo.tickerid, res, calcRatingAll())
StrongBound = 0.5
WeakBound = 0.1
getSignal(ratingTotal, ratingOther, ratingMA) =>
    float _res = ratingTotal
    if ratingSignal == "MAs"
        _res := ratingMA
    if ratingSignal == "Oscillators"
        _res := ratingOther
    _res
tradeSignal = getSignal(ratingTotal, ratingOther, ratingMA)


poscol = input(color.blue, "Buy Color")
neutralcolor = input(color.gray, "Neutral Color")
negcol = input(color.red, "Sell Color")
poscond = tradeSignal > WeakBound
negcond = tradeSignal < -WeakBound
posseries = poscond ? tradeSignal : 0
negseries = negcond ? tradeSignal : 0
count_rising(plot) =>
    v_plot = plot > 0 ? plot : -plot
    var count = 0
    if v_plot == 0
        count := 0
    else if v_plot >= v_plot[1]
        count := min(5, count + 1)
    else if v_plot < v_plot[1]
        count := max(1, count - 1)
    count
poscount = count_rising(posseries)
negcount = count_rising(negseries)
_pc = poscond ? poscount : negcond ? negcount : 0
colorTransp(col, transp) =>
    red = color.r(col)
    green = color.g(col)
    blue = color.b(col)
    color.rgb(red, green, blue, transp)
hline(1, color=colorTransp(poscol, 50), linestyle=hline.style_solid)
hline(0.5, color=colorTransp(poscol, 50), linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
hline(-1, color=colorTransp(negcol, 50), linestyle=hline.style_solid)
hline(-0.5, color=colorTransp(negcol, 50), linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
getTimeOfNextBar() =>
    currentTime = time(timeframe.period)
    changeTime = change(currentTime)
    minChange = if (not na(changeTime))
        var float minChange = changeTime
        minChange := min(minChange, changeTime)
    int(currentTime + minChange)
drawInfo(txt, value) =>
    var info = label.new(0, 0, "", yloc = yloc.price, xloc = xloc.bar_time, textalign = text.align_left, textcolor = color.white)
    label.set_x(info, getTimeOfNextBar())
    label.set_text(info, txt)
    label.set_color(info, poscond ? poscol : negcond ? negcol : color.gray)
    label.set_style(info, label.style_label_left)
calcRatingStatus(value) =>
    if -StrongBound > value
        "Strong Sell"
    else if value < -WeakBound
        "Sell"
    else if value > StrongBound
        "Strong Buy"
    else if value > WeakBound
        "Buy"
    else
        "Neutral"
MAText = ratingMAC == 0 ? "" : "MAs:     " + calcRatingStatus(ratingMA) + "\n"
OtherText = ratingOtherC == 0 ? "" : "Oscillators: " + calcRatingStatus(ratingOther) + "\n"
TotaText = "All:  " + calcRatingStatus(ratingTotal)
drawInfo(MAText + OtherText + TotaText, tradeSignal)
col_buy = color.from_gradient(tradeSignal, 0.0, 0.2, neutralcolor, poscol)
col_sell = color.from_gradient(tradeSignal, -0.2, 0.0, negcol, neutralcolor)
col_gradient = color.from_gradient(tradeSignal, -0.2, 0.2, col_sell, col_buy)
plot(tradeSignal, title="Rating", linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_columns, color = colorTransp(col_gradient, 50 - _pc * 10))
_cond1 = crossunder(tradeSignal, -WeakBound)
alertcondition(_cond1, "Sell", "Ratings changed to Sell")
_cond2 = crossover(tradeSignal, WeakBound)
alertcondition(_cond2, "Buy", "Ratings changed to Buy")
_cond3 = crossunder(tradeSignal, -StrongBound)
alertcondition(_cond3, "Strong Sell", "Ratings changed to Strong Sell")
_cond4 = crossover(tradeSignal, StrongBound)
alertcondition(_cond4, "Strong Buy", "Ratings changed to Strong Buy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything within one indicator shares the same chart scale. As such the only way to do this is to rescale the output of your indicators to match mathematically. So for example to get RSI to scale similarly to the Technical Rating you can `rescaledRSI = (rsi - 50) / 50`. Which would give you rsi bound to the range of -1 to +1 instead of 0 to 100

Comment: still not working , what if i want to change scale of technical rating to 0 to 100